# Search through Drop down list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, search, drop-down-menu

I am making a page in asp.net using C# and my page consists of two drop down list one for state and one for subjects, both the data are coming from database, and there is a third database table for storing user details and the third table consists of name class and subject

Now my problem is that on click of search button i want to search the users table and return the value selected by person searching through drop down list on the master page and the result will be displayed on the next page

Please help as to what to do for search button, and what to write on second page on which i want to display the results.

Your help is badly needed

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework assignment...  Have you tried to solve this already on your own?  What did you try, and what-if-any problems did you run into?

Here's one (of a thousand other) tutorials that will walk you through filtering a result page using a drop-down.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581789.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: ps: check out www.asp.net -- they have tons of great tutorials.  other than that, there are also some great "step-by-step" books from ms press that will give you a decent beginning.